# Updating preferences in real time

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a Preferences Screen which has some prefs that are interconnected. Which means, if I have pref `x` and `y`, I sometimes need `y` to change to something when `x` changes.

What I'm doing at the moment is listening to prefs change event, and do this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("y_pref", "somevalue");
editor.commit();
```

The problem is, that to actually see the change I have to first close the prefs screen and then open it again, only that way will I see the newly set prefs.

Is there a way to change the prefs so that the change is visible right away, without the need to reload the prefs screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call the setter of the preference itself instead updating it on your own:

E.g. [EditTextPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html).[setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29). So the preference itself updates it's own value too. If you do the update on your own the preference will not fetch the new value because it doesn't even know that the persisted value has changed.

If you have a `PreferenceFragment`, you can get the preference with [PreferenceFragment.findPreference()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

If you have a `PreferenceActivity`, you can get the preference with [PreferenceActivity.findPreference()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

You call that with the preference key you assigned in your settings XML file and you get an instance of the corresponding preference. Then you cast it to an `CheckBoxPreference`, `EditTextPreference`, etc (the type you set in your XML file).

Comment: I'll try that, but how do I get the instance of the pref element I need? (i.e. `ListPreference` or `CheckBoxPreference` etc.) thanx

Comment: Very sorry, but am being slow. I tried to search it but found nothing regarding how to get an instance of the prefs element from the prefschange listener class.

Comment: You are using a `PreferenceActivity`, right? This has the method i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: its a bit late (8 years late lol), but I want to ask, under which Override method should we create this function? I mean is it should be under onCreate? or onCreatePreferences? or onResume?