# Reset specific preferences Android

Tags: android, preferences

I've got a number of preferences that I want to reset back to the defaults specified in my preferences xml file.

I do not want to reset all of my preferences - just a few select ones.

I've tried:

```
key=getResources().getString(R.string.myPref);
sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).commit();
```

This clears the preference.  However when my program then tries to pick the preference up

```
String myPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
```

It just returns the empty string.

How do I get the value from the XML file?

Thanks

Adding more complete code sample that I've been debugging:

```
//Get preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

//Get preference key
key=getResources().getString(R.string.myPref);

//Get preference value
String myPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""); // Returns a value that has been entered by a user

//Clear preference
sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).commit();

//Reset preferences to default values - without overwritting all
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(currentContext, preferences, false);

//Get preference value again
String myPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""); // Returns an empty string
```

Comment: Of course it gets the empty string since you specified it in the `getString()` method as the default value if the key is not specified.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a more complete code sample

Comment: I've also tried reloading the shared preferences before trying to get the preference value:

//reload preferences - post reset?
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

To no avail

Answer (score 2):

Try `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);`
This is save as the last parameter ensures that user changed entries don't get overridden.

Comment: Then, you perhaps should file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

> getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context).setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, true);

Be sure to set last argument *readAgain* to **true**.

This will force to re-read the default values. If false, this method sets the default values only if this method has never been called in the past (or if the KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES in the default value shared preferences file is false). To attempt to set the default values again bypassing this check, set readAgain to true.

Comment: Hi Sanders,  I've tried that but it's not working.  I still get an empty string.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is kind of old, but hopefully [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603665/956975) might help future viewers. It really helped me.

> Quoting the answer:

Try to call the setter of the preference itself instead updating it on your own:

E.g. [`EditTextPreference.setText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29). So the preference itself updates it's own value too. If you do the update on your own the preference will not fetch the new value because it doesn't even know that the persisted value has changed.

If you have a PreferenceFragment, you can get the preference with [`PreferenceFragment.findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

If you have a PreferenceActivity, you can get the preference with [`PreferenceActivity.findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

You call that with the preference key you assigned in your settings XML file and you get an instance of the corresponding preference. Then you cast it to a `CheckBoxPreference`, `EditTextPreference`, etc (the type you set in your XML file).

---

**My personal adaptation:**

Note: I was using this in a PreferenceFragment extended class, therefore the `this.getActivity()`.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());
preferences.edit().remove(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_username)).apply();
EditTextPreference usernamePref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_username));
usernamePref.setText("");
```

Hope it helps!