# pref screen opens multiple times android

Tags: android, preferences

I have a preference on which I am dynamically putting strings and reloading the activity to show changes immediately, like this:

```
void restartActivity() {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is I am changing some other pref values when a specific one has a specific value.This causes the SHAREDPREFERENCELISTENER to run again and again causing the above method  to run again and again.

For some reason, this results in multiple pref screen being created on top.

To clear some things, I do have this:

```
@Override

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    PreferenceScreen screen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
```

Any ideas on how can I limit the function so it does not create the screens over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean value to `true` after you restarted the activity. Set it to `false` after the restart is completed. Call `startActivity` only if it is `false`.

Declare a field: `private boolean mRestarted = false;`

In `restartActivity`:

```
void restartActivity() {
    if(!mRestarted} {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        mRestarted = true;
    }
}
```

And in `onCreate:`

```
mRestarted = false;
```

This will work. But it's a bad way to refresh the values... You should do something else to reload the changes.

Comment: What doesn't work in the first place? I mean, which values are changed in preferences and not updated in the activity itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603633/updating-preferences-in-real-time: this is what I was doing......(although the method I use is not from here)

Comment: Well, it should work (Changing the value of the preference `EditText` itself, for example).