# Changing preference in OnPreferenceChangeListner in android

Tags: android, settings, listpreference

In my android app, I need **settings to select time range** (e.g. 2 to 4 minutes, 8 to 12 minutes etc).

To implement it, I used two instances of **ListPreference**, one to select minimum time and other to select maximum time.

As maximum time cannot be less than minimum time, I want to update the maximum time list preference whenever minimum time is changed by a user.

To achieve it, I am using **Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListner**. When user changes minimum time preference, the listener callback function is called and in the callback, I call **setEntries(), setEntryValues()** and **setValueIndex()** on maximum time ListPreference instance.

The problem is that **GUI of maximum time preference is not updated immediately** when I do above. I can still see old entries in the preference. If I exit settings activity and launch the settings again, I can see updated entries and values.

Please let me know how I could solve this issue.

Also, please suggest if there is any better way to handle such settings use case.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the listener is not called. Also provide some code you have done.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Parth. To post my code, I need to trim it down. I will do that. But I know that listener is called and even my calls like setEntries() and setEntryValues() in the listener callback were successful. I could see the updated entries after I exited and relaunched my settings activity.

Comment: To anyone who is searching for how to update one preference when another changes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603633/updating-preferences-in-real-time.

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, I realized my mistake. 
I did not read this [document of OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) callback:

*"Called when a Preference has been changed by the user. This is called **before** the state of the Preference is about to be updated and before the state is persisted."*

The problem was that I was querying the value of minimum time list preference in the preference change listener callback of it and generating the entries of maximum time list preference on the bases of that. But as the document reads, new value of minimum time list preference was not yet set in the callback, so the entries were generated on the basis of old values. So it was not supposed to work as I was expecting.

Sorry for not posting code as it required more effort to make the code ready for posting here.

Thanks for reading my question.