# How to update summary of preference from sub-preference

Tags: android, summary, preference

I can't solve this problem. I have preference screen and there is sub-preference that opens up another screen. On that another screen change of items can be caught with `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and I change summary in parent preference screen, but when I go back to that parent preference screen, summary did not changed.

Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396153/preferencescreen-androidsummary-update), but conclusion was not clear, and I could not solve this problem. It seems a common problem to me and I guess there is good solution for this.

Dose anyone know a solution for this problem?

- There is one thing I like to keep: sub-preference is standard one, not custom.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this by adding `OnPreferenceClickListener` to the preferences which will change the summary in the main screen.

```
OnPreferenceClickListener viewUpdater = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            updateView();
            return  false;
        }
    };
```

Within the updateView() method I'm setting the summary to a new value and then I'm using the invalidateViews method of the preferences listview to trigger an update of the displayed summary

```
private void updateView() {
    preference.setSummary(newSummary);
    getListView().invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559394/542218) of [@jmbouffard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578668/jmbouffard)  that's work for me